# Unit for testing string interpolation in Angular 4

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

In my HTML I have

```html
<label>{{placeholder}}</label>
```

where `placeholder` is a component variable. How to test string interpolation in Angular with Jasmine?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Angular CLI, it generates a basic test for you that does just this.

```
<h1>{{ placeholder }}</h1>
```

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  it('should render placeholder in a h1 tag', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('my value');
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
describe('WelcomeComponent', () => {
  let comp: any;
    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        // provide the component-under-test and dependent service
        declarations: [
          WelcomeComponent
        ]
      });

      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WelcomeComponent);
      comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('set placeholder some default value', () => {
      comp.placeholder = 'some text';
      expect(comp.placeholder).toContain('some text');
    });
});
```

Comment: It is great you want to test only the component variable. But with this approach, you can't say for sure if the data is correctly rendered in the html. Usually I like to test these both ways. First, what you proposed, the other one is accessing the template by queries and extracting the value from there.